# Swift Draw a line from center of one circle to the edge of another

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw a UIBezierPath in swift where i can get it to go from the center of a circle to another circles center but what i really want is for the line to stop at the edge of the end circle but at the point where the line would have intersected the circles edge if the line was continuating to the center of the circle and not stopping at the edge.

I need somehow to calculate the intersection point between the line and the circle. how would i be able to do that when the circles are UIImageViews with width and height of 30 (so radius 15) and i now the centers coordinates of the two circles.

[image: UIBezierPath (Line) going from center of one circle to edge of the other circle.]

Comment: can you show through image ? what you want to draw ? please attach image

Comment: are you still looking for an answer ?

Comment: Yes i am still looking for an answer so if you now a way to move the arrow i would very much appreciate it

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: I have tried making the vector for the line (x2, y2) + t * (x2 - x1, y2 - y1) the problem with this is that t is not a constant so i need a way to figure out what the right t is for each line i make. And i am not sure how to figure out what t should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

From the the set of x and y (center of circles) from now called (x, y) and (x2, y2) a vector can be made that is (x2 - x, y2 - y) where x2 - x i will call a and y2 - y i will call b then the distance of the vector can be calculates as sqrt(a^2 + b^2) where the result of i will call dist.

From this a Unit vector can be made with is (a/dist, b/dist) now all i need to do to get my new coordinates for the arrow is (x,y) as starting coordinates and (x2 + r*a/dist, y2 + r*b/dist) as the end coordinates where r is the radius of the circle at (x2, y2).

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Wix's answer is correct, but I want to clean it up for those who come here in the future.

I'm going to do this in SwiftUI.

Jump to the bottom for the math, I'm just going to define a pair of View's that draw a circle, and a line:

```
    func drawCircle(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, strokeWidth: CGFloat, color: Color) -> some View {
        Path { path in
            path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: start.x, y: start.y, width: end.x - start.x, height: end.y - start.y))
        }
        .stroke(lineWidth: strokeWidth)
        .fill(color)
    }
    
    func drawSelectionCircle(center: CGPoint, strokeWidth: CGFloat, color: Color) -> some View {
        Path { path in
            path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: center.x - (strokeWidth / 2.0), y: center.y - (strokeWidth / 2.0), width: strokeWidth, height: strokeWidth))
        }
        .fill(color)
    }
    
    func drawLine(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, strokeWidth: CGFloat, color: Color) -> some View {
        Path { path in
            path.move (
                to: CGPoint(
                    x: start.x,
                    y: start.y))
            
            path.addLine(
                to: CGPoint(
                    x: end.x,
                    y: end.y))

        }
        .stroke(lineWidth: strokeWidth)
        .fill(color)
    }
```

Ok, on to the math from Thomas Wix. I'm going to do something slightly different here, so the math may be slightly different.

We'll consider (50,50) to be our starting point, and (300,300) to be our ending point.

We'll draw both a circle and a line, and 2 intersect dots where the line intersects the circle.

NOTE: Keep in mind this won't work if the Circle is not a perfect circle.

```
            ZStack {
                drawCircle(start: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), end: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300), strokeWidth: 2, color: .red)
                drawLine(start: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), end: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300), strokeWidth: 2, color: .blue)
                drawSelectionCircle(center: intersectPoints()[0], strokeWidth: 6, color: .black)
                drawSelectionCircle(center: intersectPoints()[1], strokeWidth: 6, color: .black)
            }

    func intersectPoints() -> [CGPoint] {
        let circleStart = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
        let circleEnd = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300)
        let circleMiddle = CGPoint(x: (circleEnd.x + circleStart.x) / 2.0, y: (circleEnd.y - circleStart.y) / 2.0)
        
        //distance between firstPoint and circleEnd
        //remember Pythagoras. a^2 + b^2 = c^2 [we are figuring out c here, the length of the blue line]
        let distance = sqrt( pow((circleEnd.x - circleStart.x), 2) + pow((circleEnd.y - circleStart.y), 2) )
        let radius = (circleEnd.x - circleStart.x) / 2.0
        let intersectingLineAndCirclePoint1 = circleMiddle.x + ((radius * (circleEnd.x - circleStart.x)) / distance)
        let intersectingLineAndCirclePoint2 = circleMiddle.x - ((radius * (circleEnd.x - circleStart.x)) / distance)
        
        return [
            CGPoint(
                x: intersectingLineAndCirclePoint1,
                y: intersectingLineAndCirclePoint1
            ),
            CGPoint(
                x: intersectingLineAndCirclePoint2,
                y: intersectingLineAndCirclePoint2
            )
        ]
    }
```

This produces the following image:

[image]